# Shimano 105 FC-5501 chainrings replacement

Tags: shimano, crankset, groupsets

I have road bike with old 105 5500 2x9 groupset. My crankset chainrings worn out from wear and need to be changed. My crankset is 105 FC-5501 52/39 Octalink 130 BCD. I looked for 5500 series chainrings in e-shops, but I didn't find anything for this old model except e-bay where I can get all crankset with crank arms. Could you advise which ones of chainrings would be appropriate with FC-5501? Can I use for example a Shimano 105 5700 10 speed 130 BCD chainrings on my crankset?

Answer (score 6):

Shimano might not say it's okay, but you can use any 130BCD chainrings that you can find with that crankset[1](https://www.parktool.com/product/chainring-nut-wrench-cnw-2). You'll get the best shifting performance if you pick a matched set of chainrings from a single vendor. The one thing to avoid is any chainrings that say Narrow/wide in the description, these are 1x specific and won't work well on a double crankset.

When replacing chainrings, it's important to line them up with the crankarm for best shifting. There will be a mark or bump in the chainring that indicates where the chainring should be installed relative to the crank arm. The outer chainring generally has a small metal pin to prevent the chain getting wedged in the crank arm in addition to this bump. The whole process will be much easier if you get a chainring nut wrench like the [Park 
CNW_2.](https://www.parktool.com/product/chainring-nut-wrench-cnw-2)

If you've ridden the bike long enough to need new chainrings, you will likely need to replace the chain and cassette as well. Chainrings are generally the most durable of the 3 drivetrain components.

While you are buying stuff, get a chain checker. Replacing your chain before it wears will greatly increase the life of your chainrings and cassette.

[1](https://www.parktool.com/product/chainring-nut-wrench-cnw-2)- I know that everything up to 11 spd will work fine, I've no idea about 12 spd stuff as I have no experience with that yet.